# is |x|/x equal to x/|x|

Tags: functions, absolute-value

The derivative of absolute value is defined as x/|x|
But of course that correspond to the sign of x. So then, why can't it be interchanged in exercises resolution, as also |x|/x is equivalent to the sign of x?

Comment: Yes, $\dfrac{|x|}{x} = \dfrac{x}{|x|}$ for all real $x$.  For complex on the other hand, no, they can be different.

Comment: Yes, they are equal for non-zero $x$ since $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$, so $$\frac{\sqrt{x^2}}x=\frac x{\sqrt{x^2}}$$$$\sqrt{x^2}^2=x^2$$$$x^2=x^2$$

Comment: @JMoravitz not really for $x=0$

Comment: it is undefined in both cases for $x=0$

Comment: but you cannot really say "undefined = undefined"

Comment: For $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\},\ \dfrac{|x|}{x}=\dfrac{|x|^2}{x|x|}=\dfrac{x^2}{x|x|}=\dfrac{x}{|x|}$

Comment: My point being, in complex numbers it fails., for example $\frac{i}{|i|} = i\neq -i = \frac{|i|}{i}$

Comment: So if we just consider functions in the real numbers, can I use both as derivative in exercises?

Answer (score 1):

By definition of absolute value we have that

- for $x>0 \implies \frac{|x|}x=\frac x x=\frac x{|x|}=1$
- for $x<0 \implies \frac{|x|}x=-\frac x x=\frac x{|x|}=-1$

Comment: So can I use both as derivative in exercises?

Comment: @giancarletto Yes of course for $x\neq 0$ you acen use both of them.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $x\ne 0,$ we have $$\frac{x}{|x|}=\frac{x}{|x|}\frac{|x|}{|x|}=\frac{x|x|}{|x|^2}=\frac{x|x|}{x^2}=\frac{|x|}{x}.$$